# Is there a way to enable immersive mode on MaterialDatePicker?

Tags: android, material-ui, material-components-android, materialdatepicker

I'm developing an app in which MaterialDatePicker is used.

[Material DatePicker Fragment from app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seMPa.jpg)

The entire application is fullscreen (immersive mode enabled - status and navigation bars are hidden) and I also want this in the DatePicker dialog. I've tried multiple suggestions but nothing worked. Is there a way to achieve this?

UPDATE:

What I've tried so far:

```
    val datePickerBuilder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()

    datePickerBuilder.apply {
      setTitleText("SELECT A DATE")
      setTheme(R.style.MaterialCalendarTheme)
      setSelection(
        Pair(
          startDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli(),
          endDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli(),
        )
      )
    }


    val dp = datePickerBuilder.build()

    dp.dialog?.apply {
      window?.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
      )
      window?.decorView?.setSystemUiVisibility(dp.requireActivity().window.decorView.getSystemUiVisibility())
      setOnShowListener {
        dp.dialog?.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)

        val wm = dp.requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        wm.updateViewLayout(dp.dialog?.window?.decorView, dp.dialog?.window?.attributes)
      }
    }
```

The code snnipet from inside the second apply opperator works on other custom DialogFragmets that I've built.

After trying the above suggestion I've seen that the onCreateDialog method from MaterialDatePicker is final so an override is not possible.

Comment: Could you share what you tried so far?

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy The question is updated

Comment: The concept is absurd, because `Dialog` is not supposed cover the whole screen.

Comment: I want this screen to be consistent with the other ones. Enabling immersive mode on all screens, it just looks weird seeing the navigation and status bars on this one

Comment: @RăzvanDănilă I think I have found a solution but there are two quirks: 1. If the user uses text input instead of picking the date, the bottom bar gets shown (without the buttons for now) and that cannot be disabled as the keyboard is in focus. 2. If the user leaves the app with the recents button and returns to it while the dialog is displayed, the bottom bar is shown for a brief period when the dialog is closed. Do you want me to try fixing this or it's good enough for you?

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy Thank you for your time. I'll apreciate if you could share what you've found so far, I'll continue from that. But if you're willing to help me further, I'll be very grateful

Comment: @RăzvanDănilă I think I have finally figured out everything. I'll post a solution soon.

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy Great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that `dp.dialog` is always `null` at that point as it only gets created by the `FragmentManager` when it initializes the `DialogFragment` of the `MaterialDatePicker`, thus the UI visibility changing code never gets executed. It *could be* non-null if you showed the dialog synchronously:

```kotlin
dp.showNow(supportFragmentManager, null)
dp.dialog?.apply {
   // anything here gets executed as the dp.dialog is not null
}
```

However, ***the problem with this approach*** is that this code never gets called anymore. If the dialog is rebuilt (e.g. the device is rotated), nothing inside this block is executed anymore which would result in a non-fullscreen dialog.

Now, there is a fundamental problem with `MaterialDatePicker`: it's `final` so none of the dialog creator / handler methods can be overridden which would work in other cases.

Fortunately there is a class called [`FragmentLifecycleCallbacks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks) that you can use to listen to the (surprise-surprise) fragment lifecycle events. You can use this to catch the moment where the dialog is built which is after the view is created (callback: [`onFragmentViewCreated`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks#onfragmentviewcreated)). If you register this in your `Activity`'s or `Fragment`'s `onCreate(...)`, your date picker fragment (and hence the dialog itself) will be up-to-date.

So, without further ado, after a lot of experiments and tweaks with the different settings, the following solution might satisfy your needs (this uses an `Activity`).

> The sample project is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Gericop/Immersive-MaterialDatePicker-Sample).

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // ... setContentView(...), etc.

    registerDatePickerFragmentCallbacks()
}

// need to call this every time the Activity / Fragment is (re-)created
private fun registerDatePickerFragmentCallbacks() {
    val setFocusFlags = fun(dialog: Dialog, setUiFlags: Boolean) {
        dialog.window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)

        if (setUiFlags) {
            dialog.window?.decorView?.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener { visibility ->
                // after config change (e.g. rotate) the system UI might not be fullscreen
                // this ensures that the UI is updated in case of this
                if (visibility and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN == 0) {
                    hideSystemUI(dialog.window?.decorView)
                    hideSystemUI() // this might not be needed
                }
            }

            hideSystemUI(dialog.window?.decorView)
            hideSystemUI() // this might not be needed
        }
    }

    // inline fun that clears the FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE flag from the dialog's window
    val clearFocusFlags = fun(dialog: Dialog) {
        dialog.window?.apply {
            clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)

            decorView.also {
                if (it.isAttachedToWindow) {
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(it, attributes)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    supportFragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(object :
        FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {

        override fun onFragmentViewCreated(
            fm: FragmentManager,
            f: Fragment,
            v: View,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ) {
            // apply this to MaterialDatePickers only
            if (f is MaterialDatePicker<*>) {
                f.requireDialog().apply {
                    setFocusFlags(this, true)

                    setOnShowListener {
                        clearFocusFlags(this)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, false)
}


override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    // helps with small quirks that could happen when the Activity is returning to a resumed state
    hideSystemUI()
}

// this is probably already in your class
override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)

    if (hasFocus) hideSystemUI()
}

private fun hideSystemUI() {
    hideSystemUI(window.decorView)
}

// this is where you apply the full screen and other system UI flags
private fun hideSystemUI(view: View?) {
    view?.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
}
```

To make your `MaterialDatePicker` use the immersive mode, you need either of the following styles. The first displays a normal dialog while the second uses the full screen one, which disables the background dimming that usually happens when you open a dialog and makes sure that the dialog is displayed in a full screen window.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Normal dialog -->
    <style name="MyCalendar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
        <!-- you can use ?attr/colorSurface to remove any blinking happening during re-creation of the dialog -->
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>

        <!-- or use translucent navigation bars -->
        <!--<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>-->

        <item name="android:immersive">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    </style>

    <-- Fullscreen dialog -->
    <style name="MyCalendar.Fullscreen" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>

        <!-- you can use ?attr/colorSurface to remove any blinking happening during re-creation of the dialog -->
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>

        <!-- or use translucent navigation bars -->
        <!--<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>-->

        <item name="android:immersive">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

When you're building the dialog, just pass this style as the theme for the dialog:

```
val datePickerBuilder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()

// for a normal dialog
datePickerBuilder.setTheme(R.style.MyCalendar)

// for a fullscreen dialog
datePickerBuilder.setTheme(R.style.MyCalendar_Fullscreen)
```

This is how the fullscreen immersive dialog looks like:

[image]

And a normal immersive dialog:

[image]

> These screenshots were taken on an emulator that has navigation bar normally.